# liquibase example with google-cloud-datastore

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I need some example where we can version control our db creation for google cloud datastore.
I can see example for the google cloud mysql https://medium.com/@ramzi.maalej/micronaut-using-google-cloud-sql-9b2fc466c01a but is there any documentation by google cloud to work with the google cloud datastore and liquibase.
Any help or example on how to setup liquibase with cloud datastore will be really appreciated

Comment: Hi, seems that the liquibase tool doenst have a extension for datastore. Have you tried another tools?

Comment: @Mario Thanks alot for your help will check on other tools

Answer (score 0):

Even datastore does not offer a versioning system, maybe this could be created from the scratch using the export tool and some code in the back.
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#rest

For example Visual Studio has a tool to make migrations between the structure of the database, this is aimed to Entity Framework that maps relational databases,

But the most important approach is the thing that NoSQL databases maybe doest have context in each change.

https://guptakumartanuj.wordpress.com/2017/09/04/approaches-to-support-versioning-through-nosql-database-like-document-db/